# Get all tree from a model object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have

```
@total = Purchase::Total.find(1);

Total model have:

has_many :items
belongs_to :member
belongs_to :company
..................


Also companies model has

has_many :addresses
has_one :subscription
..................
```

and a lot more

How can I get a tree from the `@total object` containing all the `has_one`, `belongs_to` dependencies?

I.E.

```
<Purchase::Total id: 3, member_id: 4, created_at: \"2015-11-25 14:47:46\", updated_at: \"2015-11-25 14:47:46\", affiliate_company_id: nil, is_paid: false, currency: 1, company_id: 37020, ser_id: 2>
<Company id: 37020, name: \"Andrew\", parent_id: 37019, member_company_id: 37019, payment_company_id: 37019, widget_id: 3003359>
```

And so ..... (I did the example with: @total.inspect and @total.company.inspect), and I need something like `inspect` to return automatically all the objects.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`reflect_on_all_associations`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations)

1. Take a `Queue` and a `Hash` and add `Total` (model name) to it.
2. Pop a model name, get all associated models and add them queue. Also, using the [`tablize`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveSupport/Inflector/tableize) name of current model, create a new entry in hash and add the `tablize`d names of associated models.
3. If queue is not empty, go to 2.

At the end, your hash should look like:

```
{ total: { company: [ :subscription, :addresses ] }, items: { associated: { another: :another_one } } }
```

Then you can use this in your query:

```
Total.where().join(hash[:total])
```

It will fetch all the associated data as well. Then you can simply loop through the attributes. If attribute type is `ActiveRecord` (or similar), then its an associated model data.